# How to do a sliding buffer stream?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs

Given the following code where I use `bufferCount` (not quite what I want)...

```
   var Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
    var Observable = Rx.Observable;
    var Subject = Rx.Subject;

    var first = new Rx.Subject();

    var source = first.bufferCount(2).map(a => a.reduce((acc,x) => acc+x,0));

    var subscription = source.subscribe(console.log)

    first.next(1)
    first.next(2)
    first.next(2)
    first.next(3)
```

I get

```
3
5
```

what I'd like to get is

```
3
4
5
```

so the buffer is buffering the last 2 items.

Is there a way to do this simply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `bufferCount`'s `skip` / `startBufferEvery` parameter? This allows you to generate overlapping buffers, which you can then reduce as desired. This way doesn't involve emitting values you have to subsequently filter out. If you specifically want a buffer size of 2, you can use `pairwise` instead of bufferCount.

Keith:- The code using this method

```
var Rx = require('rxjs/Rx');
var Observable = Rx.Observable;
var Subject = Rx.Subject;

var first = new Rx.Subject();

var source = first.bufferCount(2,1).map(a => a.reduce((acc,x) => acc+x,0));

var subscription = source.subscribe(console.log)

first.next(1)
first.next(2)
first.next(2)
first.next(3)
```

Comment: nice, I didn't notice that sneaky parameter

Answer (score 3):

Use the `scan` operator to hold your sliding buffer, and perform operation on it. For instance :

```
var source = first.scan((slidingBuffer, newInput) => {
    return addTo(slidingBuffer, newInput)
  }, [])
  .map(processBuffer)
```

with the `addTo` and `processBuffer` functions having obvious meanings.

Comment: is there a way to return from scan without emiting anything into the stream,  for the initial case where the sliding buffer isn't full?

Comment: just return false, and filter out false values, or take care of that case in the processBuffer function

Comment: yeah, just realized I can filter it

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the array operations in conjunction with scan. This is what I'm using for a max size of 20 items.

```
first.pipe(
   scan((buffer, newItem) => ([ newItem, ...buffer].slice(0, 20)), <string[]>[])
)
```

Unlike `bufferCount()` this will emit immediately.